# Cannot create a Xamarin Cross App like the examples on internet

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I start using Xamarin and I see a lot of examples on the internet and I cannot create a project like the examples do. I mean, I follow all the steps, but when I have to select PCL, I don't have that option. If I continue, all the code have reference errors. Another thing that I don't have and in all the examples appears, is that I cannot see the New Universal Windows Project dialog.

I have different options since the project creation starts.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I put some screenshots with red squares with the new options that are different from the tutorials. I put also the tutorials I try to follow, hope it helps.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Tutorials:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/developing-first-cross-platform-mobile-app-using-visual-studio-20172/

http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/xamarin/xamarin-dvelopment-with-vs-2017

Comment: Creation of PCL libraries has been removed in recent releases, use .Net Standard 2.0 instead

Comment: Ok, thanks! Any idea of where I can find an actualized tutorial? And the other errors... are related to this?

Comment: `other errors` Not sure, but it looks look you do not have the `Xamarin.Forms` nuget package installed in the projects that the errors are showing in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.NET standard` instead of pcl libraries. Also regarding the errors just install the `Xamarin.Forms` nuget package and then use it in the `MainPage`.